# Maven Release Plugin: Where Is It Getting It's Version From?

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

When I use the Maven release plugin on a project, it's releasing the wrong thing. This seems to be a fixed bug in the version of the Maven release plugin I'm using so I'd like to update it. But I can't quite figure out where it's getting this version from.

When I run `mvn release:help` I can see that I'm running version `2.3.2`. But I can't find where this version is defined. It's not in my project's POM file. It's also not in my settings.xml file in `M2_HOME`.

I know I can fix the version for this one project but I've rather fix it in place for all projects. Anyone have idea of where I can look? Upgrading to the latest version of Maven 3.X has no affect on what plugin version I'm using.

Comment: There should be a `<version>` tag in your project, or in its parent project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is defined in the Super POM, the POM from which all other POM inherits. From [the docs of Maven 3.3.9](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html) (which is currently the latest version):

> All models implicitly inherit from a super-POM:
>   
> ...
>
> ```xml
> <plugin>
>   <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
>   <version>2.3.2</version>
> </plugin>
> ```

This POM defines global version for a couple of widely used plugins and the global default values for every Maven project. One of them is the `maven-release-plugin` and the declared version is 2.3.2.

Comment: Thanks for finding the answer for me. Guess I'm going to have to set a version in every project POM then. Oh well!

Comment: @LeeTheobald Not necessarily. You could define your own global parent that would set the version you want and let your other Maven projects inherit from it.